# Tensorflow: Sampling a tensor according to another tensor?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-probability

I have a tensor `T` of shape `Batch_Size x Num_Items x Item_Dimension` and another tensor `P` of shape `Batch_Size x Num_Items`, where the Num_Items values in each batch of P sum to 1 (a probability distribution of items for each batch). I want to sample without replacement `N` items from T according to probability distribution P. The resulting tensor should be of shape `Batch_Size x N x Item_Dimension`. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9260

Though note I believe you need logits instead of probs for Gumbel max sampling.

Comment: Yep, that’s me commenting at the bottom of that issue. Thanks! This should work but I want to find out first if it’s equivalent or an approximation. I also want to understand why using logits or probas would be better. Are you sure it should be logits? Should I just take the log of my probas?

Comment: I believe they are equivalent, not approximate. Discussed here https://timvieira.github.io/blog/post/2014/08/01/gumbel-max-trick-and-weighted-reservoir-sampling/ including a citation of Efraimidis and Spirakis (2005).

Comment: Generally for stable numerics it's advisable to do most computation in log space. I think the post I linked above is fairly clear about which equations involve probs vs logprobs.